Closed Subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$
I need help in the following problem from Wulf Rossman's book on Lie Groups.
Problem : Show that a one-parameter subgroup of an element $X \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is not closed if and only if $X$ is similar to a diagonal matrix having two eigenvalues whose quotient is not rational.
My approach : I know that one parameter subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is of the form $\phi(t) = e^{tA}$ for some matrix $A$. Also for a subgroup $X$ the corresponding one parameter subgroups are of the same form and such that $\phi(t) = e^{tA} \in X$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Now for the mapping $\phi(t)$ to be closed we must have the set of eignevalues to be a closed set, i.e $\{e^{t\lambda}: \lambda \:\:\text{an eigenvalue of} \:\: A \}$. How can I proceed from here?
I have also tried thinking in terms of closed subgroup theorem but I am not getting anywhere.

Every one-parameter subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ can be expressed as $\phi(t) = e^{tA}$ for some matrix $A$. By diagonalizing $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ (or at least reducing it to Jordan form), we find that $\phi(t)$ is conjugate to a diagonal matrix whose entries are $e^{t\lambda_1}, \dots, e^{t\lambda_n}$. Since conjugation does not affect whether the subgroup is closed, it suffices to check when
$$
\left\{ \left(e^{t\lambda_1}, \dots, e^{t\lambda_n}\right) : t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}
$$
is closed in $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^n$. This set is not closed precisely when there is at least one pair $\lambda_i, \lambda_j$ such that $\lambda_i / \lambda_j$ is not a root of unity. In that case, the subgroup becomes dense in a torus-like subset and fails to be closed. If all eigenvalue ratios are roots of unity, the image is closed. The confusion with the closed subgroup theorem typically arises because that theorem addresses algebraic closures or Lie-theoretic conditions, whereas here the problem is purely about topological closure in the exponential image of the eigenvalues.

Even if $A$ isn’t diagonalizable, use Jordan form: $A = PJP^{-1}$ where $J$ has Jordan blocks for eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$. Then $e^{tA} = P e^{tJ} P^{-1}$. For a Jordan block $B$ with $\lambda$, $e^{tB} = e^{t\lambda} e^{tN}$. Closedness depends on whether ratios $e^{t(\lambda_i - \lambda_j)}$ are dense. Thus, non-diagonalizability doesn’t affect the conclusion: the subgroup isn’t closed if some $\lambda_i/\lambda_j$ isn’t a root of unity.

But I thought the poster said he didn’t want the full answer just a guide as to what direction to go?

Very pure explanation. Thanks @Raynard Bond
